# Getting last message from each user - Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm creating an app in which I want to include chat. The last thing that I have to do is showing last message from each conversation (including those sent by me).

My Db looks like this

```
[
 {
 _id: 5f9b06cdb5d5eb3b94f066e3
 from: "5f860655e3fc7f43709cc408"
 to: "5f8b0a941efeb42a24f1f926"
 message: "123"
 createdAt: 2020-10-29T18:15:41.424+00:00
 updatedAt: 2020-10-29T18:15:41.424+00:00
 __v: 0
 },
 {
 _id: 5f9b0761b5d5eb3b94f066e5
 from: "5f860655e3fc7f43709cc408"
 to: "5f8b0a941efeb42a24f1f926"
 message: "321"
 createdAt: 2020-10-29T18:15:41.424+00:00
 updatedAt: 2020-10-29T18:15:41.424+00:00
 __v: 0
 }
]
```

Results that I want to achieve:

```
[
 {
  message: '123',
  createdAt: 2020-10-29T18:15:41.424+00:00,
  from: "5f860655e3fc7f43709cc408"
 }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Chat.findOne({_id: 0, message: 1, createdAt: 1, from: 1}).sort({createdAt: -1})

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this I think:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": {
      "createdAt": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "message": 1,
      "createdAt": 1,
      "from": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 1
  }
])
```

`sort` is to sort by date. In this case, the newest date first.

`project` is to use only these fields.

`limit` to get only the first.

Mongo PlayGround example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/v9BcPjGt2IX)

Edit:

If you want to query by conversation (with your model I don't know how to do that...) you can use `$match` and something like: `$match {"id_conver": "..."}`

For example, querying matching "from" and "to".

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "from": "5f860655e3fc7f43709cc408",
      "to": "5f8b0a941efeb42a24f1f926"
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "createdAt": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "message": 1,
      "createdAt": 1,
      "from": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 1
  }
])
```

Comment: I've got collection with all messages and I need to get only 1 from each conversation, even in only one side has sent a message. I tried to use aggregate before (https://pastebin.com/ZL0ju1LF) but it returns only messages for match: to.

Comment: And it needs to be an array 2.